# Java 8 stream objects significant memory usage

Tags: java, memory, java-8, java-stream

In looking at some profiling results, I noticed that using streams within a tight loop (used instead of another nested loop) incurred a significant memory overhead of objects of types `java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline` and `java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator`. I converted the offending streams to foreach loops, and the memory consumption decreased significantly.

I know that streams make no promises about performing any better than ordinary loops, but I was under the impression that the difference would be negligible. In this case it seemed like it was a 40% increase.

Here is the test class I wrote to isolate the problem. I monitored memory consumption and object allocation with JFR:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class StreamMemoryTest {

    private static boolean blackHole = false;

    public static List<Integer> getRandListOfSize(int size) {
        ArrayList<Integer> randList = new ArrayList<>(size);
        Random rnGen = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            randList.add(rnGen.nextInt(100));
        }
        return randList;
    }

    public static boolean getIndexOfNothingManualImpl(List<Integer> nums, Predicate<Integer> predicate) {

        for (Integer num : nums) {
            // Impossible condition
            if (predicate.test(num)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean getIndexOfNothingStreamImpl(List<Integer> nums, Predicate<Integer> predicate) {
        Optional<Integer> first = nums.stream().filter(predicate).findFirst();
        return first.isPresent();
    }

    public static void consume(boolean value) {
        blackHole = blackHole && value;
    }

    public static boolean result() {
        return blackHole;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 100 million trials
        int numTrials = 100000000;
        System.out.println("Beginning test");
        for (int i = 0; i < numTrials; i++) {
            List<Integer> randomNums = StreamMemoryTest.getRandListOfSize(100);
            consume(StreamMemoryTest.getIndexOfNothingStreamImpl(randomNums, x -> x < 0));
            // or ...
            // consume(StreamMemoryTest.getIndexOfNothingManualImpl(randomNums, x -> x < 0));
            if (randomNums == null) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(StreamMemoryTest.result());
    }
}
```

Stream implementation:

`Memory Allocated for TLABs    64.62 GB`

```
Class   Average Object Size(bytes)  Total Object Size(bytes)    TLABs   Average TLAB Size(bytes)    Total TLAB Size(bytes)  Pressure(%)
java.lang.Object[]                          415.974 6,226,712   14,969  2,999,696.432   44,902,455,888  64.711
java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2        64      131,264     2,051   2,902,510.795   5,953,049,640   8.579
java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head     56      72,744      1,299   3,070,768.043   3,988,927,688   5.749
java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1      24      25,128      1,047   3,195,726.449   3,345,925,592   4.822
java.util.Random                            32      30,976      968     3,041,212.372   2,943,893,576   4.243
java.util.ArrayList                         24      24,576      1,024   2,720,615.594   2,785,910,368   4.015
java.util.stream.FindOps$FindSink$OfRef     24      18,864      786     3,369,412.295   2,648,358,064   3.817
java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator    32      14,720      460     3,080,696.209   1,417,120,256   2.042
```

Manual implementation:

`Memory Allocated for TLABs    46.06 GB`

```
Class   Average Object Size(bytes)  Total Object Size(bytes)    TLABs   Average TLAB Size(bytes)    Total TLAB Size(bytes)  Pressure(%)
java.lang.Object[]      415.961     4,190,392       10,074      4,042,267.769       40,721,805,504  82.33
java.util.Random        32          32,064          1,002       4,367,131.521       4,375,865,784   8.847
java.util.ArrayList     24          14,976          624         3,530,601.038       2,203,095,048   4.454
```

Has anyone else encountered issues with the stream objects themselves consuming memory? / Is this a known issue?

Comment: Yeah, no, this is totally to be expected.  The overhead of streams will definitely be significant for inputs this small.

Comment: Not exactly related, but wouldn't the equivalent of `getIndexOfNothingManualImpl` be `return nums.stream().anyMatch(predicate)`?

Comment: Yes you're right. In a previous version of this, I was playing around with the actual returned value, hadn't thought to change it at the time.

Comment: I’m quite confident, that the `for` loop creates an `Iterator` implementation under the hood. Somehow, your profiler missed that…

Comment: It’s interesting that the run with the “manual” implementation (read: `Iterator` based implementation), is supposed to have created more `Random` instances, but a *significantly* less number of `ArrayList`s. How can you trust such numbers?

Comment: By the way, a JVM has no problem detecting that your `blackHole` variable is always `false`. Since it hasn’t declared `volatile`, the optimizer doesn’t have to consider updates from other threads and in your sequential code path there is no chance of it going to `true`.

Comment: Regarding the missing Iterators in the Iterator-based implementation, I had truncated the lists since the question was getting long. They were on the order of tens of kilobytes.

Answer (score 25):

Using Stream API you indeed allocate more memory, though your experimental setup is somewhat questionable. I've never used JFR, but my findings using JOL are quite similar to yours.

Note that you measure not only the heap allocated during the `ArrayList` querying, but also during its creation and population. The allocation during the allocation and population of single `ArrayList` should look like this (64bits, compressed OOPs, via [JOL](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/)):

```
 COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
     1       416       416   [Ljava.lang.Object;
     1        24        24   java.util.ArrayList
     1        32        32   java.util.Random
     1        24        24   java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong
     4                 496   (total)
```

So the most memory allocated is the `Object[]` array used inside `ArrayList` to store the data. `AtomicLong` is a part of Random class implementation. If you perform this 100_000_000 times, then you should have at least `496*10^8/2^30 = 46.2 Gb` allocated in both tests. Nevertheless this part could be skipped as it should be identical for both tests.

Another interesting thing here is inlining. JIT is smart enough to inline the whole `getIndexOfNothingManualImpl` (via `java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintCompilation -XX:+PrintInlining StreamMemoryTest`):

```
  StreamMemoryTest::main @ 13 (59 bytes)
     ...
     @ 30   StreamMemoryTest::getIndexOfNothingManualImpl (43 bytes)   inline (hot)
       @ 1   java.util.ArrayList::iterator (10 bytes)   inline (hot)
        \-> TypeProfile (2132/2132 counts) = java/util/ArrayList
         @ 6   java.util.ArrayList$Itr::<init> (6 bytes)   inline (hot)
           @ 2   java.util.ArrayList$Itr::<init> (26 bytes)   inline (hot)
             @ 6   java.lang.Object::<init> (1 bytes)   inline (hot)
       @ 8   java.util.ArrayList$Itr::hasNext (20 bytes)   inline (hot)
        \-> TypeProfile (215332/215332 counts) = java/util/ArrayList$Itr
         @ 8   java.util.ArrayList::access$100 (5 bytes)   accessor
       @ 17   java.util.ArrayList$Itr::next (66 bytes)   inline (hot)
         @ 1   java.util.ArrayList$Itr::checkForComodification (23 bytes)   inline (hot)
         @ 14   java.util.ArrayList::access$100 (5 bytes)   accessor
       @ 28   StreamMemoryTest$$Lambda$1/791452441::test (8 bytes)   inline (hot)
        \-> TypeProfile (213200/213200 counts) = StreamMemoryTest$$Lambda$1
         @ 4   StreamMemoryTest::lambda$main$0 (13 bytes)   inline (hot)
           @ 1   java.lang.Integer::intValue (5 bytes)   accessor
       @ 8   java.util.ArrayList$Itr::hasNext (20 bytes)   inline (hot)
         @ 8   java.util.ArrayList::access$100 (5 bytes)   accessor
     @ 33   StreamMemoryTest::consume (19 bytes)   inline (hot)
```

Disassembly actually shows that no allocation of iterator is performed after warm-up. Because escape analysis successfully tells JIT that iterator object does not escape, it's simply scalarized. Were the `Iterator` actually allocated it would take additionally 32 bytes:

```
 COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
     1        32        32   java.util.ArrayList$Itr
     1                  32   (total)
```

Note that JIT could also remove iteration at all. Your `blackhole` is false by default, so doing `blackhole = blackhole && value` does not change it regardless of the `value`, and `value` calculation could be excluded at all, as it does not have any side effects. I'm not sure whether it actually did this (reading disassembly is quite hard for me), but it's possible.

However while `getIndexOfNothingStreamImpl` also seems to inline everything inside, escape analysis fails as there are too many interdependent objects inside the stream API, so actual allocations occur. Thus it really adds five additional objects (the table is composed manually from JOL outputs):

```
 COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
     1        32        32   java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator
     1        24        24   java.util.stream.FindOps$FindSink$OfRef
     1        64        64   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2
     1        24        24   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1
     1        56        56   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head
     5                 200   (total)
```

So every invocation of this particular stream actually allocates 200 additional bytes. As you perform 100_000_000 iterations, in total Stream version should allocate 10^8*200/2^30 = 18.62Gb more than manual version which is close to your result. I think, `AtomicLong` inside `Random` is scalarized as well, but both `Iterator` and `AtomicLong` are present during the warmup iterations (until JIT actually creates the most optimized version). This would explain the minor discrepancies in the numbers.

This additional 200 bytes allocation does not depend on the stream size, but depends on the number of intermediate stream operations (in particular, every additional filter step would add 64+24=88 bytes more). However note that these objects are usually short-lived, allocated quickly and can be collected by minor GC. In most of real-life applications you probably should not have to worry about this.

Comment: Wow great answer.

Comment: As a point of clarification, when you say that there are too many interdependent objects inside the stream API, do you mean in general or in this scenario?

Comment: @BryanJ, both. Escape analysis is a very fragile thing. A little step aside from some known patterns and it simply gives up like "or, I'm not sure whether these objects not escape the method, so better to allocate them". E.g. if you allocate two objects and link them to each other, current implementation of EA will definitely fail, even if they don't escape.

Answer (score 7):

Not only more memory due to the infrastructure that is needed to build the Stream API. But also, it *might* to be slower in terms of speed (at least for this small inputs).

There is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8oN4KSZEXE) presentation from one of the developers from Oracle (it is in russian, but that is not the point) that shows a trivial example (not much more complicated then yours) where the speed of execution is 30% worse in case of Streams vs Loops. He says that's pretty normal.

One thing that I've notice that not a lot of people realize is that using Streams (lambda's and method references to be more precise) will also create (potentially) a lot of classes that you will not know about.

Try to run your example with :

```
  -Djdk.internal.lambda.dumpProxyClasses=/Some/Path/Of/Yours
```

And see how many additional classes will be created by your code and the code that Streams need (via ASM)

Comment: technically, under ideal circumstances, streams can also be faster for array lists since their spliterators only have to do the concurrent modification check once.

Comment: dumpProxyClasses have nothing to do with streams, it's internal implementation of lambdas runtime representation. If you use lambdas without streams (like OP does) you will have them as well.

Comment: @TagirValeev of course you will still use proxy classes, I should have said that more clear, thx for comment, will edit.